# ¿Desde cuándo se usa la palabra "alma" como "vírgen, doncella"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, historia, palabras-raras, diccionarios

El [Diccionario de la lengua española](https://dle.rae.es/) de la Real Academia Española recoge, desde la edición de 1992, la entrada [alma<sup>2</sup>](https://dle.rae.es/alma#1vWbh0u) como

> Del hebr. *‘almá*.
>
> 1. f. p. us. Virgen, doncella

Personalmente nunca he encontrado ese vocablo en textos españoles comunes, salvo en comentarios a  Isaias 7:14 en los que se debate sobre si la traducción del hebreo *‘almá* al griego *parthenos* es correcta o errónea y si eso a su vez ha influido en el texto de Mateo 1:23.

¿Se utiliza / ha utilizado en español tanto como para que la Real Academia Española lo incluyera en su diccionario en 1994 pero al mismo tiempo lo marque como p. us.? ¿Desde cuando se ha utilizado?

Adenda: El [Fichero General](http://web.frl.es/fichero.html) de la Real Academia Española tiene 4.842 fichas para "alma" y, de un modo similar, el CORDE, CREA y CORPES XXI tienen miles de entradas lo que hace inviable consultarlas a mano.

Comment: Mea culpa, mea maxima culpa.

Answer (score 2):

Buen descubrimiento. He estado buscando textos en el CORDE y he encontrado textos de los siglos XVI y XVII que asemejan el alma a una virgen doncella, pero no es que a una virgen o doncella se la llame "alma". Véase por ejemplo el siguiente texto:

> *Ahí es donde el alma, como doncella y virgen, se ocupa en hacer sus labores muy a lo divino con menos peligro y más seguridad.*
>
> San Juan Bautista de la Concepción (Juan García López), "El recogimiento interior", a 1613 (España).

O este otro:

> *El alma es la doncella de buena casta, pues es de casta de Dios.*
>
> Fray Alonso de Cabrera, "De las consideraciones sobre todos los evangelios de la Cuaresma", a 1598 (España).

Así presentados los textos pueden inducir a equívoco, pero por el contexto en el que aparecen yo aseguraría que se refieren al concepto tradicional de *alma*.

No he encontrado nada que haga referencia a que *alma* se pueda haber usado como sinónimo de "virgen, doncella", pero sí varias de estas comparaciones. Tampoco he encontrado en el NTLLE entradas en ningún diccionario de la época que presente alguna definición así.

En textos modernos tampoco he encontrado nada, aunque como dices es complicado buscar dada la cantidad de información que hay y lo común que es la palabra.